# How to label the Vertex and, or Edge labels with their weight

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I noticed that the Mathematica 9.0 documentation only mentions the usage of "Name" to label the vertexlabel or edgelabel in the Graph.
Is there an option to use the Weights automatically just as "Name" does?

Comment: Could you please split this into a separate question and answer to comply with the format of the site?  [It is okay to answer your own question.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok no problem. Is this ok?

Answer (score 6):

I found that "EdgeWeight" and "VertexWeight" are next to "Name" also possible candidates.

```
Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, VertexWeight -> {100, f[x], 300}, 
 EdgeWeight -> {10 || 20, Prime[x], g[x]^2}, 
 VertexLabels -> "VertexWeight", EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", 
 ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This was discussed in the [mathgroup](http://comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica.narkive.com/qH31k36M/vertexweight-not-showing-in-graph) a year ago. Apparently this was documented in 8.0.0 and disappeared in later versions.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes that is correct. At that time this option however didn't work and got removed from the docs. Apparently it got fixed but the documentation was not updated. VertexWeight was also missing in the 8.0 docs.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries http://stackoverflow.com/q/7381085/353410

Comment: @belisarius Totally forgot that we had that discussion there as well. I checked that it doesn't work in 8.0.4, but it does in 9.0.1.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emAe6IClGys

Comment: This option isn't in the documentation!  I've reported this absence